# Handling change for dynamic input field in components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

The state of array values is not changing i have tried many times but still not succeeded is there a way that i missed somehow here is the attached code highlighting the problem. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Class component handling form stepper

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      step: 1,
      propertyID:0,
      responseMessage:"",    
      loading:false,
      name:"",
      address: "",
      county:"",
      city: "",
      zipcode: "",
      type: "",
      specifictype: "",
      formValues:[{beds:"",rent:"",numUnits:0,squarefeet:""}]
    };
  }
handleFormChange(i, e) {
    let formValues = this.state.formValues;    
    console.log(formValues);
    formValues[i][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ formValues });
  }
  render() {
    const { step } = this.state;
    const {
      address,
      name,
      specifictype,
      city,
      county,
      zipcode,
      type,
      formValues,
      responseMessage
    } = this.state;
    const values = {
      address,
      name,
      specifictype,
      city,
      zipcode,
      type,
      county,
      formValues,
      responseMessage
    } ;

    switch (step) {
      
      
      case 3:
        return(
            <PropertyType
                values={values}
                add={this.addFormFields.bind(this)}
                remove = {this.removeFormFields.bind(this)}
                handleChange={this.handleFormChange}
                prevStep={this.prevStep}
                nextStep={this.getandSend}

            />
        )
     
    }
  }
```

then here is the code of the component that handles the dynamic input fields.I had to reduce the code other parts are working fine do not worry about values,add,remove,prevStep and next step those are working just fine the problem is how i handle the change

```
function PropertyType({values,add,remove,handleChange,prevStep,nextStep}) {

return(
<>
 <form action="">
                            {values.formValues.slice(0,5).map((element, index) => (
                            <div className="w-full md:w-9/12 flex mx-auto">
                                <div className="mb-6 mr-3">
                                    <label
                                        className="block mb-2 text-coolGray-800"
                                        htmlFor=""
                                    >
                                        Beds
                                    </label>
                                    <select defaultValue={element.beds} onChange={e => handleChange(index, e)} className="block w-full p-3 leading-5 text-coolGray-900 border border-coolGray-200 rounded-lg shadow-md placeholder-coolGray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-color-main focus:ring-opacity-50 bg-white" aria-label="Default select example">
                                        <option selected>Select bedrooms</option>
                                        <option value="0">Studio</option>
                                        <option value="1">One</option>
                                        <option value="2">Two</option>
                                        <option value="3">Three</option>
                                        <option value="4+">More than 4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div className="mb-2 mr-3">
                                    <label
                                        className="block mb-2 text-coolGray-800 font-medium"
                                        htmlFor=""
                                    >
                                        Number of units
                                    </label>
                                    <input
                                        defaultValue={element.numUnits}
                                        onChange={e => handleChange(index, e)}
                                        className="appearance-none block w-full p-3 leading-5 text-coolGray-900 border border-coolGray-200 rounded-lg shadow-md placeholder-coolGray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-color-main focus:ring-opacity-50"
                                        type="number"
                                        placeholder="10"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="mb-2 mr-3">
                                    <label
                                        className="appearance-none block mb-2 text-coolGray-800 font-medium"
                                        htmlFor=""
                                    >
                                        Squarefeet
                                    </label>
                                    <input
                                        defaultValue={element.squarefeet}
                                        onChange={e => handleChange(index, e)}
                                        className="appearance-none block w-full p-3 leading-5 text-coolGray-900 border border-coolGray-200 rounded-lg shadow-md placeholder-coolGray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-color-main focus:ring-opacity-50"
                                        type="number"
                                        placeholder="2000"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="mb-2 mr-3">
                                    <label
                                        className="block mb-2 text-coolGray-800 font-medium"
                                        htmlFor=""
                                    >
                                        Rent
                                    </label>
                                    <input
                                        defaultValue={element.rent}
                                        onChange={e => handleChange(index, e)}
                                        className="appearance-none block w-full p-3 leading-5 text-coolGray-900 border border-coolGray-200 rounded-lg shadow-md placeholder-coolGray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-color-main focus:ring-opacity-50"
                                        type="number"
                                        placeholder="30,000"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                {
                                    index ?<div className="mb-2 mr-3 mt-8">
                                            <button  className=" inline-block py-3 px-7 mb-4 w-full text-base text-white font-medium text-center leading-6 bg-red-500/50 rounded-md shadow-sm
                                            " onClick={remove}>Remove</button> </div>

                                        : null
                                }

                            </div>
                            ))}

</>

)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the answer for anyone who might need it

```
class Apps extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
       formValues: [{ name: "", email : "" }]
     };
    
  }
  handleChange(i, e) {
    let formValues = this.state.formValues;
    formValues[i][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ formValues });
  }
  render() {
    const {formValues} = this.state;
    return (
        <PropertyType values={formValues}  handleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the propertytype component

```
{values.map((element, index) => (
            <div className="form-inline" key={index}>
              <label>Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" value={element.name || ""} onChange={e => handleChange(index, e)} />
              <label>Email</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" value={element.email || ""} onChange={e => handleChange(index, e)} />
              {
                index ? 
                  <button type="button"  className="button remove" onClick={() => remove(index)}>Remove</button> 
                : null
              }
            </div>
          ))}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the reference of the `formValues` array with `spread operator`.

```
handleFormChange(i, e) {
    let formValues = this.state.formValues;    
    console.log(formValues);
    formValues[i][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ formValues: [...formValues ]});
}
```

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 1):

you have to make a copy of reference and then update as below:

```
handleFormChange = (i, e) => {
        const formValues = [...this.state.formValues]; 
        const res = formValues.map((val,idx)=>{
           if(idx == i){
             return ({...val, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
           }
           return val
        }) 
        this.setState({ ...this.state, formValues: res});
    }
```

Comment: it brings an error of this is undefined at console

Comment: oh my bad, you can use arrow function to get rid of it 

Comment: it still brings the same error i tried fixing with bind this but it does not work still

Comment: the idea is same, not sure what is causing the error tbh ...